# How does the Facebook "profile" access request provide age information?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql, facebook-ios-sdk

I was looking up the Facebook [docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/login/#permissions) on permission arrays, and understand that in order to obtain an user's birthday information it must be explicitly requested via `user_birthday`.  However, I noticed that app such as the one screencapped below do not ask for birthday information, but vaguely asks for "profile", and yet is able to obtain my exact birthday in age (not just age range). I was wondering how this is still accomplished?  Thanks!

[image]

Note that this translates to the following:

[image]

Comment: You mean that without asking for bday permission, you are able to retrieve bday?

Comment: @Shadowfax - yes, and specifically I want to understand what is meant by "profile" in the image shown.  I had always thought that age must be explicitly requested from the user as a specific entity.

Comment: @Daspianist - I have a permissions explorer (based on the Graph API Sample) for iOS. Would you like me to post a response with the source to this? (was thinking of throwing it up on git anyway)  I tried to find the answer, but couldn't get the exact set of perms it took to get that request (iOS7 aside), even if I went in and made my birthday public, the "me" record still didn't contain my birthday.

Comment: @eric - If you could post a response it'd be great.  I'm a bit hazy on what you meant by the response with the source.. but I think anything bit helps :)

Comment: It's important to note that this screen shot is from iOS 7. On a first glance, this permissions dialog looked like a dialog not generated by Facebook but by the app itself. (The pre-iOS 7 permissions dialogs looked a lot different.)

Comment: @Sebastian, that's a good point. But in this case, the facebook's permission dialog will be appeared too, don't you think so?

Comment: Not sure I understand correctly, but if the screen shot were *not* Facebook's permissions dialog, the question why it wouldn't explicitly show the birthday permissions in the dialog would be irrelevant, because it would be a developer's choice what to show in it.
Since it *is* in fact Facebook's permissions dialog, the question is legitimate, although easy to answer. (Facebook simply combined the separate permissions into one word.)

Comment: @Sebastian - +1.  As a follow up question, what I am curious is which permissions automatically gets rolled into "profile".  From a UX perspective, certainly a *shorter* permission request on the user would seem less intrusive, although in this instance it is actually asking for a lot.

Comment: Not sure it's really worth doing that - Facebook's experimenting with these settings all the time. It's totally possible that this dialog will change again until iOS 7 gets released.
(That was why I initially suggested adding the info that this is iOS 7-related. This stuff changes all the time. They're basically trying to find the balance between getting as many people to connect while combating spammy apps & keeping user complaints to an (acceptable) minimum - all the time.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Daspianist,

I've put my sample (based on FB's Graph API Sample App) App into git at: https://github.com/brewmium/Facebook-iOS-GraphExplorerQueryRunner.git

You can ask for permissions one by one, on the iOS device, and run the complex Graph API Queries generated from: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer

I wrote (heavily modified) this because the output from the web based explorer queries return VERY different results than when run on from the iOS SDK.

While I was at it, I wrote a little permissions request interface, so it's easy to modify the permissions as you are testing your queries (like on the web version).

When removing permissions, it's best that you go into your Facebook Account Settings / Apps and remove the GraphApiSample from the list of those Apps with permissions, then ask for the fresh permissions.

Good luck,

-eric

Followup: @Daspianist, My sample query runner uses the "twitch out to facebook" for login, so I see all of the permissions, vs. the dialog you screen captured... which is obviously "simplifying things"...  Here is Tinder trying to login, and it IS asking for the birthdate. I would call this a bug, NOT the ability to circumvent the permissions scheme.  Hope this helps. -eric

[image]

Comment: Thanks for posting this Eric.  Would you mind using your explorer to try to reproduce the displayed permission request from the above screenshot.  I think that would be really helpful - thanks!

Comment: The posting is really helpful - thank you! I am still surprised how in native iOS one small word "profile" could translate to so many permissions being asked.  The less descriptive and short the permission requests are, the more likely users will accept, especially in cases such as this.

Comment: I agree! it seems a little...  not right. If I run across a better answer, I'll let you know.